# How to output end task time base on start time, duration and working time in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I'm using a spreadsheet to perform calculations and I'd like to make a task management file. For example:

Working Time: 8:00 ~ 17:00
Lunch Break: 12:00 ~ 13:00

```
+- Start Time -+- Duration -+- End Time  -+
|  2/24 08:30 -+-   2:30   -+- 2/24 11:30 |
|  2/24 11:30 -+-   4:00   -+- 2/24 16:30 |
|  2/24 16:30 -+-   2:30   -+- 2/25 10:00 |
```

Does anyone know if this is possible? I want to calculate "End Time".

Answer (score 1):

**`=A2+$E$1+$E$2`** is same like:
**`=A2+TIME(8,0,0)+TIME(1,0,0)`**

[image: 1]

---

**`=A2+B2`**

[image: 1]

---

**`=C9-B9`** - total lunch time
**`=E9-A9-D9`** - total worked hours

[image: 2]

---

**`=A16+F16+D16`** - your end time

[image: 5]

---

## **[demo spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1iQCLR2uZvS3fdJ863KI8O-uvEyb4sNAjagcBECoY0x4/edit?usp=sharing)**